# Bimodules over a categorical monad

Tags: category-theory, modules, monads, bimodules

In category theory a monad consists in an endofunctor $M\colon \mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ together with natural transformations $\mu \colon M \circ M \Rightarrow M$ and $\eta \colon Id_{\mathcal{C}}\Rightarrow M$ satisfying the usual associativity and unitality conditions.

The idea is to generalize the usual notion of monoid to a category not having a monoidal structure: indeed, if $(\mathcal{C}, \otimes, 1)$ is a monoidal category and $A$ is a classical monoid then $A\otimes - \colon \mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ is a monad.

For a monad $M$ we can define the category of modules (also called algebras) over it by considering the objects $x \in \mathcal{C}$ with an action map $\rho \colon Mx\rightarrow x$ satisfying the same relations as for the algebraic counterpart.

In commutative algebra for a fixed ring $R$ we can define left $R$-modules and right $R$-modules. Moreover, we can define the opposite ring $R^*$ with multiplication $a\ast b=ba$, it follows immediately that $(R^*)^*\cong R$ and left $R^*$-modules coincide with right $R$-modules (and vice versa right $R^*$-modules are left $R$-modules).

We can put together two compatible actions of $R^*$ and $R$ and obtain a $R$-bimodule. That is, we require an abelian group $N$ to have a left and a right $R$-action such that $a(nb)=(an)b$ for all $a,b \in R$ and $x \in N$.  This is equivalent to $N$ having the structure of left $R^e$-module where $R^e=R\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R^*$.

My question is the following: can we transpose the notions of left/right modules and bimodules also for a categorical monad?
From what I illustrated I would think that we need only to define for a generic monad $M$ its opposite $M^*$ in sensible way, but I have never seen such construction anywhere.

Comment: Yes: see here https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/module+over+a+monad the first lines of the "Modules" section. One should always say that $T$-algebras in $Cat$ are left modules, but I've never seen ayone doing it...

Comment: @fosco I don't think that right $T$-modules and right $M$-modules are really related when $T=M\otimes (-)$ though, are they? In particular, right $T$-modules aren't left $T$-modules for some dual or opposite monad.

Comment: I might be missing something, but I think it depends on what you define to be an "opposite monad": for $M\otimes -$ there is such a thing, no? The new multiplication is the old one precomposed with the symmetry of $\otimes$, if present, or alternatively a monoid $M$ wrt $\otimes$ stays a monoid wrt $\otimes^{op}$ and algebras swap side...

Comment: I think Arlin's question was on the line "if we take the monad $T=M\otimes-$ then  do the right $T$-modules in the categorical sense presented in the nlab page you linked coincide with the usual notion of right $M$-modules?".
More generally, as I asked in my question, we do not have with this definition that left $T$-modules coincide with right $T^*$-modules (and vice versa) for some opposite monad $T^*$ to be defined.